# ngModel is not a known property even with FormsModule

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-forms, ngmodel

I have a unique issue with my machine I have Angular CLI 8.0.29 installed.
I've started facing issue in one project. Then I've created new project using CLI to check if anything gone wrong during boilerplate creation.

I am using [(ngModel)]="myMsg" on HTML input.

```
<input [(ngModel)] ="myMsg"/>
```

In app.module.ts I have FormsModule in imports.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [BrowserModule,
                 FormsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap:    [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In app.component.ts I have variable myMsg declarations.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Employee} from './employee';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    myMsg = 'Hello World';
}
```

I am getting this error in all projects.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your IDE cache, run your npm clear cache and do npm install.
As I am unable to repro your issue. May be above things might solve your issue.

Please find the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7a5uco?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Small issue which I saw but may be due to your export from the project you have unnecessary import, `import {Employee} from './employee';`

Comment: No even if I removed that. That don't solve the issue but I'll check for cache thing

Comment: did you checked if it is resolved?